# Java process command with file name space in it

Tags: java, linux, shell, process

I have below linux command running through java program , where input file name has space in it ,  while executing system fails

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "tsp -I afmarker": error=2, No such file or directory
```

Command :

```
String[] commandArr = new String[] { "tsp -I afmarker", "/home/test/prad test.mpg" "-P afmarker -a 10 -v 20 -O file", "/home/prad/output.mpg};

Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandArr);
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: What have **YOU** tried so far? Have you checked if the directory really exists and is accessable?

Answer (score 2):

When invoked with an array of Strings, `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` expects the first element of the array to be the name of the executable, without any parameters. If I am not mistaken, your code is instructing your JVM to execute a command called `tsp -I afmarker`, and such command does not exist. All parameters to `tsp` should be specified separately as elements of the array passed to `exec()`.

Comment: passing a string won't work because `/home/test/prad` and `test.mpg` will be interpreted as separate parameters.  Also, passing arguments as an array is better than trying to escape.

Comment: Gumboots You answer is right. Passed all parameter separately as elements to  an array.  Thank you so much.

Comment: @jnylen I thought that `/home/test/prad` and `test.mpg` **where** separate parameters, despite the very clear question made by @pradeep-poojari :-(. Agreed, an array of Strings is the only way to go, editing my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Try separating each argument instead:

```
String[] commandArr = new String[] {
    "tsp", "-I", "afmarker",
    "/home/test/prad test.mpg",
    "-P", "afmarker", "-a", "10", "-v", "20",
    "-O", "file", "/home/prad/output.mpg"
};
```